# How to get the project name in build.gradle in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, gradle

How to get the project name in **build.gradle** in **android studio**?

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                    variant.outputs.each { output -> String projectName = project.name
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**app-release.apk** can be replaced by **your-project-name.apk**

```
buildTypes {
   release {
     applicationVariants.all { variant ->
       variant.outputs.each { output -> String projectName = getRootProject().name 
                                     output.outputFileName = projectName + ".apk"
    }
}
```

OR

```
    buildTypes {
   release {
     applicationVariants.all { variant ->
       variant.outputs.each { output -> 
                              output.outputFileName = getRootProject().name + ".apk"
    }
}
```